# how to wait for dynamically started multiple threads in python to finish

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I am using `threading` in python to spawn multiple threads dynamically. This is how I am spawning the threads:

```
def func(max_val):

    for val in range(0,max_val):
        thread1 = threading.Thread(target=func9, args=(val,))
        thread1.start()

    print 'Ended all threads' #this should get printed once all the threads have ended
    # bunch of other code after this
    .
    .
    .


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ret = func()
```

What I want that once all the threads have been spawned then process should wait till all the threads have ended and then proceed with next line in code. I know that we use `thread1.join()` to wait for a thread but if I place this inside the `for` loop then it will wait for 1st thread to end before spawning the next thread. I don't want it to wait for one thread to end before starting the next thread. It should spawn all the threads simultaneously and then wait for all of them to end before executing next line in code (like the `print` in `func()` above should be executed once all the threads have ended).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you keep them in a list?

```
threads = []

for val in range(0,max_val):
    thread1 = threading.Thread(target=func9, args=(val,))
    thread1.start()
    threads.append(thread1)

for thread in threads:
    thread.join()
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be checking if `thread` is the `current thread` as to avoid `deadlock` situation?

Comment: @KhalilAmmour-خليلعمورwhat kind of deadlock are you mentioning about?

Comment: From Python Docs: 
>join() raises a RuntimeError if an attempt is made to join the current thread as that would cause a deadlock.

Comment: @KhalilAmmour-خليلعمور, I actually didn't know this way was not `thread-safe`. Can you please add the *right* way of doing it as another answer? Thanks.

Comment: @Sait Posted as answer

Answer (score 2):

Referring to Python [Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join):

> join() raises a RuntimeError if an attempt is made to join the current
>   thread as that would cause a deadlock. It is also an error to join() a
>   thread before it has been started and attempts to do so raises the
>   same exception.

You can do it this way without even saving them to a list (Example taken from [here](http://pymotw.com/2/threading/#enumerating-all-threads)):

```
main_thread = threading.currentThread()
for t in threading.enumerate():
    if t is main_thread:
        continue
    t.join()
```

`enumerate()` returns a list of active Thread instances